# How to backup Swype personal dictionary?

Tags: backup, swype

How do I backup my Swype personal dictionary ?

I Googled and found a thread on the Swype forums: [Backing up and restoring your user dictionary (ROOT USERS ONLY)](http://forum.swype.com/showthread.php?3703-Backing-up-and-restoring-your-user-dictionary-ROOT-USERS-ONLY)

I followed the exact procedure but somehow its not working. I am not able to see old words. Did it work for anyone?

I even used Titanium backup to restore but still of no use.

Can someone tell me how to backup and restore my Swype personal dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

With Version 1.3, this is now an option in Swype. You have to log in with your credentials (I think you probably registered when you downloaded the beta installer). It gives you the option to backup and sync your dictionary across other devices using Swype.

http://www.swype.com/about/specifications/

Answer (score -1):

I have version 2.0.2xxx, and it's a setting that is automatic after it's checked.  It used to be annoying in previous vers; after updates the personal dictionary would get lost, but that is cured now.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question clearly ,please consider adding further details like where is this setting ...